# mobile Web application slow on android stock browser

Tags: css, css-transitions, single-page-application

Have developed a mobile website which is specifically not responsive\slow on android stock browser of S3\S4 devices with Jelly Bean OS ( 4.0 - 4.3 ). 
But on the same devices performance is better for chromium browser. 
And on devices with Kitkat OS or even on Iphone devices speed is good on there respective native browsers as well.

Technology used is  Single Page Application Framework along with core libraries such as Knockout.js, Sammy.js, Require.js, Router.js etc along with HTML5 and CSS3. CSS3 transitions are also implemented. And we are also using css.less files

Major issues which we are getting are
**a.** increased loading time of views
**b.** transitioning is sluggish and user is unable to interact with the application for some amount of time.
**c.** Response time is slow when user clicks on Action button on the view or even when tries to navigate between pages

Any help on why the application might be slow on version ( 4.0  - 4.3 ) S3/S4 devices stock browser will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has their own way of functioning mostly depends on which browser engine it is using. Like Chrome browser use Webkit engine. It also depends how these engine has been wrapped for its best performance in default condition. Its valid too for garbage collection implementation. I will suggest you to optimize your code. Handle JavaScript memory leakage and dangling DOM objects.

[This blog](https://upvishal.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/memory-management-in-single-page-application/) can be helpful.